# Routing issue - only() method does not follow the same behavior with except() method

Tags: laravel, routes

I build an application and I try to limit the allowed methods/ endpoints. Particularly, I would like to allow only the index request and for the rest of, to throw a MethodNotAllowed exception with status code 405. For this, I tried to use the methods only() and except(). Although I expected both methods to have the same behavior, they don't.
In the first case ( using except() ), my application acts as expected but in the second case, a NotFoundException is thrown,with status code 404.
So, my question is, why the two methods are working in a different way? as it supposes that they have the same purpose, which is to restrict the allowed methods.
Thank you

`Route::jsonApiResource('my-endpoint', MyController::class)->except(['store', 'update', 'destroy']); Route::jsonApiResource('my-endpoint', MyController::class)->only(['index']);`